# Either remarking or remarked

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

The country is witnessing troubled times and petitions in Supreme Court should not exacerbate the situation, CJI **remarking** while hearing request to list a case seeking declaration of CAA as constitutional.

I think **remarking** and **remarked** both are correct here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this sentence:

- There should be quotes around the first part of it, if it is a quotation (something somebody said).
- There are a couple of missing commas that really should be present (one after "troubled times" and one after "CJI remarked").
- "hearing request" is not right.  If it is intended to be singular, then it needs either an indefinite or definite article ("a" or "the") before "request".  Alternately, if you meant it to be plural then it doesn't need an article, but it needs to be "requests".
- "remarking" is not right in this context.  The -ing form of a verb (known as the *present participle*) can not be used as a verb by itself (it is actually a noun or an adjective when used by itself).  It can be combined with "to be" to make the *present continuous* verb form ("is remarking"), but you must include the "is" for that.

So you could say "CJI is remarking", but this implies that the event is happening *right now*, which is probably not the case here.  In this case, assuming that the remark occurred previously, you need to use the *past* tense "remarked".

> "The country is witnessing troubled times, and petitions in Supreme Court should not exacerbate the situation," CJI remarked, while hearing a request to list a case seeking declaration of CAA as constitutional.